# How to keep the same form of a Qt Quick application after resizing window

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

The problem is that after I build the app on low-resolution Android devices the screen doesn't look compatible. There is not enough spaces for some pages of application. For instance text inputs overflow the screen, some pages have half view images. I would like the application must keep its form even though I resize it to the minimal screen. There are examples in Qt Software like Gallery sample which can be scalable. But I couldn't find what I missed.

Here is part of my application:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Universal 2.0
import Fluid.Controls 1.0

Flickable {
    id:optionsPage
    anchors {
        left: parent.left
        top: parent.top
        bottom: parent.bottom
        margins: 5
    }
    width: parent.width
    clip: true
    contentHeight: Math.max(optionsColumn.implicitHeight, height)
    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}
    z: 2
    Material.background: "white"
    Material.elevation: 1
    Universal.background: Universal.accent
Column{
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    id:optionsColumn
    spacing: 40
    anchors.fill : parent
    anchors.topMargin    : 15
    anchors.bottomMargin : 15
    anchors.leftMargin :15
    anchors.rightMargin  : 15
TextField {
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    id:abg_to3
    anchors.margins: 1
    Text {
        color: "#002aff"
        anchors.right: abg_to3.left
        text: "(AB): "
        font.pointSize: 15
    }
}
TextField {
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    id:beta_to3
    anchors.margins: 1

    Text {
        color: "#002aff"
        anchors.right: beta_to3.left
        text: "Beta: "
        font.pointSize: 15
    }
}
Row{
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    spacing:50
    Button {
        id:hesapla_to3
        text: "Calculate"
    }
    Button {
        id:sil_to3
        text: "Delete"
    }
}
Column{
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    spacing: 50
    TextField {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        id:bcg_to3
        anchors.margins: 1

    Text {
        color: "#002aff"
        anchors.right: bcg_to3.left
        text: "(BC): "
        font.pointSize: 15
    }
}
    Rectangle{
        id:reco
        height:geri.height
        width:geri.width
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        Image {
            id:geri
            source:"../images/third.png"
        }
      }
  }
}
}
```

This is normal app.
[image]

This is after resizing the window.

[image]

Comment: The only issue that I see is with the image. It looks to me as though you are sizing the rectangle to the image, rather than the image to the rectangle. Look at the "Image.Stretch" property.

Comment: I edited it like [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24921504/) but it didn't scaled automatically. It is not only for images but also for another widgets like [this](https://ibb.co/jDQ8L5). There are examples about this in Qt's Examples like Interactive Mobile Phone Example, Qt Quick Extras Gallery. When I scale the examples everything scales directly proportional.

Answer (score 0):

For the image you should specify a width and a height proportional to the size of the parent or the device and use Image.PreserveAspectFit as fillMode.
For the font, I think you should use a factor ratio which depends on the resolution of the screen, there is an example here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/scalability.html#calculating-scaling-ratio
There might be problems with the margins too and once again the use of a ratio might be the solution.
More generally If you want a full scalable application, there are a few rules that can help you, you can find them here : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/scalability.html
Hope it helped.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't understand the documentation so I couldn't apply them to my project. fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit works for images but  text inputs arent flexible yet. It appears when I installed it to small screen mobile devices.